# How to use SSH with Tor?

Tags: ssh, tor

How can I use an SSH client over Tor in Ubuntu 11.10? I already have Tor running (and successfully anonymizing HTTP traffic).

Answer (score 11):

With `Tor` running, you can use `torify` command.
Eg:

```
torify ssh user@remotehost
torify curl curlmyip.com
```

Answer (score 8):

From 
http://www.howtoforge.com/anonymous-ssh-sessions-with-tor:

Add the following block to the top of your `~/.ssh/config file.`

```
Host *
CheckHostIP no
Compression yes
Protocol 2
ProxyCommand connect -4 -S localhost:9050 $(tor-resolve %h localhost:9050) %p
```

Comment: You need to install package `connect-proxy` for this to work (source: http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/08/msg01213.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `proxychains` for it. It comes preconfigured to use a local tor proxy. Also you might want to avoid using DNS names on such activities as those might resolve the IP outside of tor, which is unwanted. (Thugh I hadn't checked if this is the case or not when using proxychains out of the box.)

Answer (score 1):

If `torify` fails on your platform then try this :

Install `connect` in your path, maybe by building [`connect.c`](https://github.com/Shumen/ssh-proxy) from source.

Create a script called `ssh-tbb` :

```
#!/bin/bash
export CONNECT_PASSWORD=""
exec ssh -o ProxyCommand="connect -5 -S 127.0.0.1:9150 %h %p" $*
```

You could make other programs like `git` work by creating scripts like this `git-tbb` one :

```
#!/bin/bash
export GIT_SSH=`which ssh-tbb` git pull
exec git $*
```

Rename them to `-tor` if you change the port to 9050 for the default tor config, as opposed to TBB's default 9150.

Comment: What is "connect"? What is "TBB"?

Comment: ssh-proxy's `connect.c` is here : https://github.com/Shumen/ssh-proxy

Comment: TBB stands for Tor Browser Bundle.  TBB's tor daemon runs on port 9150, while a system tor daemon runs on port 9050 by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just install tor using

```
sudo apt-get install tor -y
```

and then user ssh as

```
tor ssh user@ip_of_server -p port
```

Simple as that